# require('core-js/es6/map') polyfill not working for spread Map object on IE11

Tags: javascript, typescript, internet-explorer, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I use `TypeScript` and `Babel`.

I have code like:

```
 const map1 = new Map(...);
 const map2 = new Map(...);
 const foo = [...map1, ...map2];
```

If I import just:

```
require('core-js/es6/map');
```

above code (spreading) not work as expect (`IE 11`), but if I import:

```
require('core-js');
```

code works as expect.

How to import just necessary  functionality for spread `Map` objects?

Comment: `[...Map` A `Map` is a built-in object (on newer browsers), that's probably not what you want? (pick another name)

Comment: Sorry, it was more pseudo code, i changed it :D

Comment: [Have you taken a look through the docs?](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#ecmascript-collections) It says how to import what you need, the difference between `es` and `feature`, and so on

Comment: Yes, I tried it. 'Module not found: Can't resolve 'core-js/features/map''. I checked node_modules folders, no features directory exist

Comment: What do you means `not work as expect`?

Answer (score 1):

I've found that it needs

`import 'core-js/fn/symbol/for';`

Answer (score 0):

You should give a try with [`babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread/). In my case, when using `babel-preset-env`, object spreading was not available by default.

Comment: I tried. Not help for me. I am interested why code works when import all 'core-js', but not works when include  only 'core-js/es6/map'. So it means that nesseray functionality exist in core-js library